# How to reference a DLL file in Jelastic Tomcat

Tags: java, servlets, ddl, jelastic

I have successfully developed and deployed a java servlet in a tomcat server.

But in that servlet i call a dll file. In my computer that i run the tomcat server and i call the library
i use `System.load("C:/java/src/calldllfile.dll");` and it works fine .

The problem is that in jelastic tomcat i don't really know what path i should use and where i should place my dll file for my servlet to call... and i catch in my code with a try it returns a UnsatisfiedLinkError
so it really must be the path ...

Following a similar answer in jelastic forum that is on comments below
i tried to set my file into home folder and call it with

`System.loadLibrary(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/"+"calldllfile.dll");` 
but it didnt work.

So i don't really know what to do ... i include below an image of my deployed servlet with the location of the dll library that i cannot call. It would be just really helpfull if someone tell me what path i should use in System.load("?????");. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you already tried this? http://community.jelastic.com/index.php/topic/121-how-to-load-a-native-dllso-in-apache-tomcat/

Comment: yes i did what the guy sais there, i upload in home my dll and then try to call it ... but still the same problem...

Comment: if only someone could explain me what is the path to WEBINF for example in jelastic...i printer "user.home" and /opt/tomcat/temp comes up so how can i get my dll in there so i can call it ?

Answer (score 2):

Folders **webapps** and **home** are located on the same level and the root folder for them is **/opt/tomcat/** (equivalent of environment variable CATALINA.HOME - [portion of docs](http://jelastic.com/docs/environment-variables)). If you are talking about WEB-INF folder which is definitely located under your context (ROOT for example), to get it you need to use /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF (or   System.getProperty("catalina.home")+ "webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/").

Concerning .dll libs you can check [this](http://community.jelastic.com/index.php/topic/543-tomcat-dll-access/)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but the answer can be useful for someone.

To access the home folder from a Tomcat installation you have to use the real path `/opt/tomcat/`

This way you can access your dll with the path `/opt/tomcat/temp/calldllfile.dll`